# Issues with select drop down filtering django

Tags: django

I have issues getting the output of my `experience_level` and `country` select fields despite my best efforts,please kindly help,below are snippets of my code for better understanding

**choice.py**: File to store all my selections:

```
salary_choices = {
    '100000': '$100,000',
    '200000': '$200,000',
    '300000': '$300,000',
    '400000': '$400,000',
    '500000': '$500,000',
}

Country_choices = {
    'US': 'United States',
    'AF': 'Afghanistan',
    'AL': 'Albania',
    'DZ': 'Algeria',
}

experience_level = {
    'EXP': 'Experienced(5years and above)',
    'INT': 'Intermediate(2-5years)',
    'JU': 'Junior(0-2years)',
    'INTE': 'Intern'
}
```

**views.py**:

```
def jobsearch(request):
    queryset_list = JobListing.objects.order_by('-list_date')
    # Keywords
    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)
    # city
    if 'city' in request.GET:
        city = request.GET["city"]
        if city:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city__iexact=city)
        # country
    if 'country' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET["country"]
        if q:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(country__iexact=q)
        # experience
    if 'experience' in request.GET:
        experience = request.GET["experience"]
        if experience:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(experience_level__exact=experience)
        # Price
    if "salary" in request.GET:
        salary = request.GET["salary"]
        if salary:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(salary__exact=salary)
    context = {'salary_choices': salary_choices,
               'experience_level': experience_level, 'country_choices': Country_choices,
               'jobs': queryset_list,
               }
    return render(request, 'joblistings/jobsearch.html', context)
```

**template**:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group"><input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control right-bor"
                                        id="joblist"
                                        placeholder="Search by keyword"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group"><input type="text" name="city" class="form-control right-bor"
                                        id="location"
                                        placeholder="Search By City.."></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>
                <select class="form-control" name="country">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Country</option>
                    {% for key,value in country_choices.items %}
                        <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>
                <select class="form-control" name="experience">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="true" >Experience level</option>
                    {% for key,value in experience_level.items %}
                        <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>
                <select class="form-control" name="salary">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="true">Salary (Any)</option>
                    {% for key,value in salary_choices.items %}
                        <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search Job</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the form with the name fields supposedly to tally with the items from the get request:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import JobListing
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .choices import Country_choices, salary_choices, experience_level
from django.db.models import Q
# Create your views here.
def jobs(request):
    joblisting = JobListing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)
    """
    Getting pages from the database
    """
    paginator = Paginator(joblisting, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_joblistings = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {
        'jobs': paged_joblistings
    }
    return render(request, 'joblistings/joblistings.html', context)
def job(request, joblisting_id):
    joblist = get_object_or_404(JobListing, pk=joblisting_id)
    context = {
        'job': joblist
    }
    return render(request, 'joblistings/joblisting.html', context)
def jobsearch(request):
    queryset_list = JobListing.objects.order_by('-list_date')
    # Keywords
    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)
    # city
    if 'city' in request.GET:
        city = request.GET["city"]
        if city:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city__iexact=city)
        # country
    if 'country' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET["country"]
        if q:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(country__iexact=q)
        # experience
    if 'experience' in request.GET:
        experience = request.GET["experience"]
        if experience:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(experience_level__exact=experience)
        # Price
    if "salary" in request.GET:
        salary = request.GET["salary"]
        if salary:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(salary__exact=salary)
    context = {'salary_choices': salary_choices,
               'experience_level': experience_level, 'country_choices': Country_choices,
               'jobs': queryset_list,
               }
    return render(request, 'joblistings/jobsearch.html', context)
```

Below is my **models.py** file which shows my models:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from recruiters.models import Recruiter
# Create your models here.
class JobListing(models.Model):
    recruiter = models.ForeignKey(Recruiter, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    stack = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    experience_level = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    optional_photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    optional_photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    optional_photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my **html** code:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group"><input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control right-bor"
                                    id="joblist"
                                    placeholder="Search by keyword"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group"><input type="text" name="city" class="form-control right-bor"
                                    id="location"
                                    placeholder="Search By City.."></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 ">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>
            <select class="form-control" name="country">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Country</option>
                {% for key,value in country_choices.items %}
                    <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>
            <select class="form-control" name="experience">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="true" >Experience level</option>
                {% for key,value in experience_level.items %}
                    <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>
            <select class="form-control" name="salary">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="true">Salary (Any)</option>
                {% for key,value in salary_choices.items %}
                    <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search Job</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mention there's an issue with `experience_level` variable, but it's used in a multiple places across your code and it's not obvious where is the issue, so please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of the whole codebase. Thanks

Comment: can you share your urls.py as well ? your template comes from the jobs function ? because you don't pass experince_level in the context